# why does rsync not update times on remote even when itemize changes shows time differences

Tags: linux, rsync, nfs

I'm using rsync to sync files from one NFS mount to another NFS mount. Files exist at the remote location already because of a previously executed scp command from the local mount. The consequence of the scp command was that all files on the remote location were assigned new modification times.

The rsync command I'm now using is:

```
rsync -azvi /path/to/files/ user@remotehost:/path/to/files
```

For all of the files, the output of each change is: `<f..tp.....`

This indicates to me that rsync believes the file is being sent to the remote location because the times and permissions are different.

After rsync completes, the modification times on the remote location are not modified (i.e., they match the times assigned during the first scp command).

Why is rsync not syncing the timestamps shown in my "local" /path/to/files/?

Comment: the `p` in the change summary makes it look like rsync might not be able to set attributes like modification time or permissions on the remote system?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with NFS to know if it allows changing the modification date on files; you could test with something like `touch --reference=/some/older/file /some/NFS-mounted/file` and see if the mod time changes to match the reference file. Also, I'm confused about what's on what machine here; do you have something like NFSserver1 -> local host -> remotehost -> NFSserver2?

Comment: Are you setting the modification times _backwards_? It might be that the NFS service is caching the newer times w.r.t the actual files on disk. If you repeat the `rsync` does it try updating the same set of files once more or does it consider no work remains? If you `ssh user@remotehost` and look at the files has the metadata been correctly updated or is it visibly wrong?